# Can't see Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

I'm trying to kick off an App to be compatible with Android 2.3.3 (API 10). For some reason on Eclipse, the only option I see is 2.1 (API 7). I've installed every package in SDK involving 2.3.3 except for DroidRAZR because the connection keeps resetting when I try to download.

Any reason why I won't be able to see 2.3.3 as an option for starting a project?

Comment: have you updated to ADT revision 20?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, I'm up to date on everything.

Comment: Did it work with ADT revision 19? Did you recently update?

Comment: Are you running the SDK manager from within eclipse?  Perhaps you have two different SDK installations on your machine?  What subdirectories exist in the platforms/ directory of your SDK installation?

Comment: It actually never worked for me. I've always only been able to do work with API 7 or 15. I just updated yesterday.

Comment: Hey Chris Stratton! You were right, I have two different installations. One directory has only API 7 and 15, and the other has all the other APIs. I definitely want to get rid of the smaller one. How do I redirect the path to the bigger?

Comment: in Eclipse Window> Preferences > Android and there you can set your SDK to the right folder.